# vb.net conversion from string error

Tags: vb.net

In my VB application, i am receiving this error message:

> Conversion from string "Inv,1234,10/09/2015,Integra,1234" to type 'Double' is not valid.

the line of code is:

```
sage_string = "Inv," + customer_accountnumber + "," + InvoiceDate.Text + "," + _
    customer_company_name + "," + invoice_number + "," + "4001," + "VoIP Call Charges," + _
    Val(actual_detail_amount.ToString("F2")) + "," + "Standard," + _
    Val(actual_detail_amount * (vat_percentage / 100).ToString("F2")) + "," + _
    Val(actual_detail_amount + (actual_detail_amount * (vat_percentage / 100) _
    ).ToString("F2")) + ", , , ,"
```

`actual_detail_amount` and `vat_percentage` are both numbers that i am doing calculations with

what have i done wrong here?

Comment: Use `&` instead of `+`

Comment: Turn `Option Strict On` use it, it can be your best friend till the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are using the `+` opreator between a string a number, VB tries to convert the string to the same type as the number.

Use the `&` operator instead, which makes sure that both operands are strings:

```
sage_string = _
  "Inv," & customer_accountnumber & "," & InvoiceDate.Text & "," & _
  customer_company_name & "," & invoice_number & "," & "4001," & _
  "VoIP Call Charges," & Val(actual_detail_amount.ToString("F2")) & "," & _
  "Standard," & Val(actual_detail_amount * (vat_percentage / 100).ToString("F2")) & "," & _
  Val(actual_detail_amount + (actual_detail_amount * (vat_percentage / 100)).ToString("F2")) & _
  ", , , ,"
```

Comment: my error is now saying 'Conversion from string "F2" to type 'Integer' is not valid.'

Comment: @charlie That's because there is a problem in the above code. A copy paste won't work. One of the `+` operators was improperly replaced with `&`.

Comment: It won't let me change it, the change is too small.

Comment: @Thomas: I could change it. Thanks for spotting it.

Answer (score 0):

i have this working now by using the solution from **Guffa** and also removing the `Val()` around the values and the `.ToString("F2")` at the end of the numbers

Comment: Did you change the `&` operator in your equation? If not, you'll get something that works, but it may not be correct.

Comment: The `Val` calls serves no purpose, but the `.ToString("F2")` calls seems to be intended to limit the number of decimals in the calculation. You might want to use `Math.Round(... ,2)` to limit the decimals, or use `.ToString("F2")` on the entire numeric value if you want a specific format.

Answer (score 0):

The `+` operator is the arithmetic addition. Use `&` for string concatenation.

However, using `String.Format` would make the whole expression easier to write and read:

```
actual_detail_amount = Math.Round(actual_detail_amount, 2)
Dim vat = Math.Round(actual_detail_amount * (vat_percentage / 100), 2)
Dim total = actual_detail_amount + vat

sage_string = _
  String.Format("Inv,{0},{1},{2},{3},4001,VoIP Call Charges,{4},Standard,{5},{6}, , , ,", _
    customer_accountnumber, InvoiceDate.Text, customer_company_name, invoice_number,
    actual_detail_amount, vat, total)
```

Also using `Val(x.ToString("F2"))` for rounding is not a good solution. Use `Math.Round(x, 2)` instead. It has been made for exactly this purpose.

Assigning the calculations to local variables makes it even easier to read.

One more thing: Use the `Decimal` type for money calculations, rather than `Double`. `Double` uses a binary representation internally. This can introduce additional rounding errors for fractions. `0.1`, for instance, cannot be represented as a finite fraction in binary form, just as `1/7` in decimal representation.